# Dynamic server usage: Page couldn't be rendered statically because it used `nextUrl.searchParams` in Next.js version 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-api-router

I am in very critical trouble, let me explain

I am creating a full stack application with next js 13,
I have created an API that is perfectly working in dev(npm run dev) mode but the problem is when I give the build command(npm run build) then it shows the flowing error.
Please anybody bring me out of the problem.
Error Screenshot - https://prnt.sc/VaN1wHifqK_2

```
 [Error]: Dynamic server usage: Page couldn't be rendered statically because it used `nextUrl.searchParams`. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/dynamic-server-error
```

Here is my code.
This is the API function for getting users from the database using url searchParams

```
// /backend/apiControllers/getUsers.js

import prisma from "@/prisma/prismaClient";

export const getUsers = async (request) => {
  const { nextUrl } = request; // here is the problem, this is working for dev mode but not in production build mode.
  const email = nextUrl.searchParams.get("email") || "";
  const phone = nextUrl.searchParams.get("phone") || "";
  const id = nextUrl.searchParams.get("id") || "";

  let queryParam = {};

  if (email) {
    queryParam = {
      where: {
        ...queryParam.where,
        email: {
          equals: email,
          mode: "insensitive",
        },
      },
    };
  }
  if (phone) {
    queryParam = {
      where: {
        ...queryParam.where,
        phone: {
          equals: phone,
        },
      },
    };
  }
  if (id) {
    queryParam = {
      where: {
        ...queryParam.where,
        id: {
          equals: id,
        },
      },
    };
  }

  try {
    const users = await prisma.users.findMany(queryParam);
    return users;
  } catch (error) {
    return { apiMessage: { errorMsg: "Unable to find User details" } };
  }
};
```

And I have called that function into /app/api/armies/route.js

```
// /app/api/armies/route.js

import { getUsers } from "@/backend/apiControllers/getUsers";
import { connectDB } from "@/backend/utils/dbConnect";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const GET = async (request) => {
  try {
    await connectDB();
    const users = await getUsers(request); //called here
    return NextResponse.json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json({
      apiMessage: { errorMsg: "Internal Server Error, Please try again later" },
    });
  }
};
```

I have tried the following method also "const url = new URL(request.url);" but the same error, Here is the error screenshot - https://prnt.sc/Z3D317lDQ3CP

```
import prisma from "@/prisma/prismaClient";

export const getUsers = async (request) => {
  const url = new URL(request.url); // here is the problem, this is working for dev mode but not in production build mode.
  const email = url.searchParams.get("email") || "";
  const phone = url.searchParams.get("phone") || "";
  const id = url.searchParams.get("id") || "";

  let queryParam = {};

  if (email) {
    queryParam = {
      where: {
        ...queryParam.where,
        email: {
          equals: email,
          mode: "insensitive",
        },
      },
    };
  }
  if (phone) {
    queryParam = {
      where: {
        ...queryParam.where,
        phone: {
          equals: phone,
        },
      },
    };
  }
  if (id) {
    queryParam = {
      where: {
        ...queryParam.where,
        id: {
          equals: id,
        },
      },
    };
  }

  try {
    const users = await prisma.users.findMany(queryParam);
    return users;
  } catch (error) {
    return { apiMessage: { errorMsg: "Unable to find User details" } };
  }
};
```

But again the same error

Comment: Much of the data in a Request is not available until it has been [fetched](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch).  Before then, the data is not available.  When you try to dereference `request` (i.e. `const { nextUrl } = request`) Nextjs is aware that the request data being available is dependent on an unfulfilled promise and is pretty much telling you that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Next.js, Every page and route handler are static by default then Next.js will (bail out) opt out to dynamic rendering when using Runtime data such as `searchParams` or `headers`. The way Next.js knows when dynamic data is used is by throwing custom errors and catch them to switch the renderer method. Simply, when you use the request URL (e.g. `request.nextUrl`) Next.js internally will throw `DynamicServerError` and catch it at a top-level.

> While generating static pages, Next.js will throw a DynamicServerError if it detects usage of a dynamic function, and catch it to automatically opt the page into dynamic rendering. However, when it's uncaught, it will result in this build-time error.
>
> [Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/dynamic-server-error)

Let's look at this snippet from your code:

```js
try {
    const users = await getUsers(request); //called here
    // At the previous line, We used `request.url` / `request.nextUrl`
    // Next.js has thrown a `DynamicServerError`

    return NextResponse.json(users);
  } catch (error) {

    // Wait!
    // We are trying/catching errors here, so any thrown error withen 
    // the try block will no longer be thrown. As a result, 
    // Next.js no longer knows when you use dynamic data
 
    return NextResponse.json({
      apiMessage: { errorMsg: "Internal Server Error, Please try again later" },
    });
  }
```

*Note**: Read the comments in the code block if you haven't

Did you get it?

### How to solve it?

We have two solutions:

1. Use dynamic data outside of `try/catch` statments

```js
const searchParams = request.nextUrl.searchParams

try {
    const users = await getUsers({ searchParams });
    return NextResponse.json(users);
    // ...
```

This way, Next.js will throw its errors and catch them without a stumbling block.

2. Re-throw Next.js errors:

You can also, catch all errors then re-throw Next.js-specific errors to handle them. Next.js provides some utilities to know the error.

```js
import { isDynamicServerError } from "next/dist/client/components/hooks-server-context";

// ...

try {
  const {nextUrl} = request;
} catch (error) {
  if (isDynamicServerError(error)) {
    throw error;
  }

  // handle other errors
}
```

When using some of Next.js functions inside `try` you need to re-throw them. for example, `isNotFoundError` for `notFound()`, `isRedirectError` for `redirect`.

```js
import { isStaticGenBailoutError } from "next/dist/client/components/static-generation-bailout";
import { isNotFoundError } from "next/dist/client/components/not-found";
import { isRedirectError } from "next/dist/client/components/redirect";
import { isDynamicServerError } from "next/dist/client/components/hooks-server-context";
```

> **Note*: If anyone is interested in fixing grammar mistakes in my answer, feel free to hit the edit button*

Comment: Appreciate your response @Ahmed!!

Answer (score 1):

in next.js, in general, if you reference a dynamic variable in a page, that page becomes dynamic. Because, if you think about it, `useSearchParams` reads and manipulates the URL's query parameters in the browser. This means the content or behavior of the page can change without a full page reload, based solely on changes to the URL's query string. That is why,this page cannot be rendered as static

Comment: but how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

According the instruction in Next.js docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/app-static-to-dynamic-error), you can use `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';` like in the bellow example:

```js
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'; // <- add this to force dynamic render

export const getUsers = async (request) => {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
...
```

In my code, i used it like this:

```js
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

export async function GET(req: Request) {
   const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
...
```