Next.js 14 render page by router params gets npm build error
Next.js 14: Dynamic server usage error during build for email verification flow
I'm working on an email verification flow using Next.js 14, and I'm encountering issues during the build process. In development, everything works fine, but during the build, I get a dynamic server usage error related to my API route.
Here’s an overview of my setup:
User clicks the verification link in the email:
The verification link points to a frontend page like /verify?token=abcd1234.
Frontend page (/verify):
The frontend page retrieves the token from the URL and sends a fetch request to the backend API route to verify the token.
Backend API route (/api/auth/verify):
The API route processes the token, verifies it against the database, and returns a JSON response indicating the verification status.
Here is the relevant frontend code:
'use client';

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { Nav } from "@/app/components/Nav";
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

export default function Verify() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('Verifying...');
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const token = searchParams.get('token');

  useEffect(() => {
    async function verifyToken() {
      if (token) {
        try {
          const res = await fetch(`/api/auth/verify?token=${token}`);
          const data = await res.json();

          console.log(data);
          if (data.status === 'success') {
            setMessage('Congratulations! Your email has been successfully verified.');
          } else if (data.status === 'expired') {
            setMessage('Verification token has expired. Please request a new one.');
          } else {
            setMessage('Verification failed. Please try again or contact support.');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          setMessage('An error occurred during verification. Please try again or contact support.');
        }
      }
    }

    verifyToken();
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Nav />
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-yellow-700">
        <div className="bg-white p-8 rounded shadow-md text-center dark:bg-yellow-500">
          <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4 dark:text-white">Email Verification</h1>
          <p>{message}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Suspense>
  );
}



Here is the relevant backend API route code:
import { db } from '@vercel/postgres';

export async function GET(request) {
  try {
    const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
    const token = searchParams.get('token');

    if (!token) {
      return new Response(
        JSON.stringify({ status: 'error', message: 'No token provided' }),
        {
          status: 400,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      );
    }

    const client = await db.connect();

    const tokenQuery = `
      SELECT user_id, created_at, used FROM schema."email_verification" WHERE token = $1
    `;
    const tokenResult = await client.query(tokenQuery, [token]);

    if (tokenResult.rows.length === 0 || tokenResult.rows[0].used) {
      client.release();
      return new Response(
        JSON.stringify({ status: 'error', message: 'Invalid or used token' }),
        {
          status: 400,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      );
    }

    const { user_id, created_at } = tokenResult.rows[0];
    const tokenAge = (new Date() - new Date(created_at)) / 1000 / 60; // in minutes
    const tokenExpiry = 4320; // 3 days in minutes

    if (tokenAge > tokenExpiry) {
      client.release();
      return new Response(
        JSON.stringify({ status: 'expired', message: 'Token expired' }),
        {
          status: 400,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      );
    }

    const updateQuery = `
      UPDATE schema."user"
      SET confirmed = true
      WHERE user_id = $1
    `;
    const result = await client.query(updateQuery, [user_id]);

    if (result.rowCount === 0) {
      client.release();
      return new Response(
        JSON.stringify({ status: 'error', message: 'Failed to update user' }),
        {
          status: 500,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      );
    }

    // Mark the token as used
    const markTokenUsedQuery = `
      UPDATE schema."email_verification"
      SET used = true
      WHERE token = $1
    `;
    await client.query(markTokenUsedQuery, [token]);

    client.release();

    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ status: 'success', message: 'Email verified successfully' }),
      {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error verifying email:", error);
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ status: 'error', message: 'Internal server error' }),
      {
        status: 500,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
    );
  }
}


The errors I’m seeing during the build process:
Dynamic server usage: Route /api/auth/verify couldn't be rendered statically because it accessed `request.url`. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/dynamic-server-error


What I’ve tried:
Ensuring that useSearchParams is wrapped in a Suspense boundary.
Adjusting the frontend and backend logic to ensure JSON responses and proper error handling.
Using useEffect in the frontend to ensure the verification request is only made once.
Question:
How can I properly handle the email verification flow in Next.js 14 to avoid these build errors?
Specifically, how can I resolve the dynamic server usage and suspense boundary issues while ensuring that the verification logic works correctly during both development and build processes? All works in dev mode, but gets npm build wrongs.
I got a URL param (token) from the router, which is causing server-side dynamic rendering issues and errors. It's incredibly frustrating that there isn't a workaround. When I'm in development mode, everything is fine, but when I try to build, it throws constant errors.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78010468/18079514

I spent 10 hours to solve this problem, saw a lot of people mentioned a solution :
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';


it doesn't work for me.
I find a new solution. Move all logic to route.js (backend) , and use
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';
export const runtime = 'edge'; // solve everything 



The document is here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config
